# CSS: show triangles in a row

Tags: css

My *HTML* markup with *CSS* can be seen in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kpatel/PrDyq/). Here, you can see that the last triangle with the box is looking fine. Actually, here I have made 3 triangles with the boxes. In every `box-1-wrap, box-2-wrap` and in `box-3-wrap` there is one box and a triangle is made.

Now, I want the triangle of the first div to be shown. They are in a line. So here I want the first row to show just above the second box and the second triangle should be shown above the 3rd  box.

Can someone here kindly help me out here?

Here's how the output file should look like:

[image]

Comment: Is `position: absolute` a possibility?

Comment: error is in ur css code.

Comment: It's because every next box covers previous.

Comment: @amrit_neo can you tell me what is the error in the css? You can give me link of your css file

Comment: @andrewpey so is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is position each consecutive box *under* the previous one.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.box-1-wrap{
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}
.box-2-wrap{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
.box-3-wrap{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/PrDyq/11/

Answer (score 0):

```
.box-1-wrap, .box-2-wrap, .box-3-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
.light-blue-box {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  height: 0;
  background: #2D98F0;
  display:inline-block;
}
.arrow-first {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 20px solid #2D98F0;
border-top: 20px solid #2B90E3;
border-bottom: 20px solid #2B90E3;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
}
.light-blue-box-2 {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  height: 0;
  background: #2B90E3;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 0 0 -4px;
  z-index:999;
}
.arrow-second {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid #2B90E3;
border-top: 20px solid #2879BB;
border-bottom: 20px solid #2879BB;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 -5px
}
.light-blue-box-3 {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  height: 0;
  background: #2879BB;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 0 0 -4px;
  z-index:999;
}
.arrow-third {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid #2879BB;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 -5px
}
```

Add this code and check

Comment: first error was the next box was covering the first one. So I changed it and instead of using transparent used the color of previous box

Comment: nop...there is one white line is still there..You can check it http://jsfiddle.net/kpatel/M6pgz/

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution with less css and less html: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5pTR/1/

Supporting IE <9 would require manually annotating the first and last elements rather than using `first-child`; adding one placeholder in the end rather than using `:after` and finally not using css3's `hsla`.